# Unable to fetch download urls from firebase storage

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I have uploaded some files in my firebase storage in the images folder

[image: The main folder]

[image: Contents of the folder]

Now I wanted to get the download URLs for those files using listAll and getDownloadURL methods, but both of them are not fetching any info

I have a ref that should point to the images folder in storage

```
 const downloadImgRef = ref(storage, " images/ ");

 useEffect(() => {


    // listAll(downloadImgRef).then((res)=>{
    //   console.log(res);
    // })

    getDownloadURL(downloadImgRef).then((res)=>{
      console.log(res);
    })

  
  }, []);
```

I used both of them, but none of them are showing the desired results.
[image: listAll() is returning an empty object]

[image: getDownloadURL() shows this error]

Answer (score 2):

You indeed need to use the [`listAll()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/storage#listall) method as follows:

```
// Create a reference under which you want to list
var listRef = ref(storage, "images/");

// Find all the items.
listAll(listRef)
  .then((res) => {
    // Call N times in parallel the asynchronous getDownloadURL() method
    const promises = [];
    res.items.forEach((itemRef) => {
      const promiseURL = getDownloadURL(itemRef);  // Promise that resolves with the download URL  
      promises.push(promiseURL);
    });
    return Promise.all(promises)
  .then((arrayOfURLs) => {
    // Do whatever you want with arrayOfURLs
    console.log(arrayOfURLs);
    arrayOfURLs.forEach(URL => {...})
  }).catch((error) => {
    // ...
  });
```

Note the following points:

- `listAll()` returns a [`ListResult`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/storage.listresult) object which has an `items` and a `prefixes` properties. Here we use `items` since you want to list all images under the `images` "folder".
- Since we want to execute several call **in parallel** to the **asynchronous** `getDownloadURL()` method, we need to use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).
- For a large list of files, use the paginated [`list()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/list-files#paginate_list_results) method as `listAll()` buffers all results in memory.

Comment: Hey @Doomstroyer, did you have the time to look at the proposes solution?